# Higher order functions with varying parameters in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code repeated over and over again:

```
def foo(data):
    result = (0, 0, 0)
    var1, var2, var3 = init_variables(data)
    for i in xrange(var1):
        result[0] += variable_func_1(data, var2, var3)
        result[1] += variable_func_2(data, var3)
        result[2] += fixed_func()
return result
```

Across all repetitions everything is fixed except for `variable_func_n` which can take a variable number of arguments, the number of these functions also varies.

I'd like to factor out the common code across all these functions so the first thing that comes to mind is to make use of higher order functions like so:

```
def foo(data, func_list):
    var1, var2, var3 = init_variables(data)
    results = (len(func_list) + 1) * [0]
    for i in xrange(var1):
        for j, func in enumerate(func_list):
            results[j] += (func(data, var1, var2, var3))
        results[len(func_list)] += fixed_func()
    return results
```

The problem with this solution is that it requires me to modify the signature of all the varying functions such that they can take more parameters. Is there a cleaner solution that wouldn't require me to modify the signature of all the passed in functions?

Comment: Maybe you could use keyword arguments (kwargs)?

Comment: kwargs would require me to modify the signature of every function I pass in unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any regularity in the parameters taken by the varying functions? Like, any inspectable rule that says it should be `variable_func_1(data, var2, var3)` and not  `variable_func_1(data, var3, var2)`? If there is no such rule, then I believe what you are asking for is not possible. Even `inspect` cannot tell which value should go to which position.

Comment: There is such a rule but I think relying on it will make for brittle code. `inspect` is probably going to be the best solution without refactoring I imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the `inspect` module?

```
In [11]: import inspect

In [12]: def f(a, b): pass

In [13]: inspect.getargspec(f)
Out[13]: ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

This library can tell you the number of arguments in each function, as well as the  name of each parameter, so you could then add your own logic to make sure the function is called correctly.

The real answer is that you might need to refactor your code, this pattern seems a little strange to me to be honest..

Comment: That is a cool function :o Didn't know that one.
Take my upvote!

Comment: I agree that the pattern is a bit strange. For context the varying functions are particularly compute intensive and so I don't want to call them all when it wouldn't be necessary, they also return different values so I don't want to put them all within a big if/elif statement in one function and get that function to return differing values.

Comment: Using inspect is bad practice, a hack. If possible, you should strive to get your functions API such that it's useful without hacks, especially if you're thinking of using inspect on your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this, is to simply pass a List that includes all data.

You could also give each function optional arguments but that would not help much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a limited number of functions, how about creating an argument lookup table? It does insert an extra layer of redirection and duplicates some info, but then again it could replace a lot of other copypasted functions if I understand correctly:

```
func_sigs = {
    func1: ['data', 'var2', 'var3'],
    func2: ['data', 'var3']
}

def call_func(f, data, var1, var2, var3):
    args = [locals()[key] for key in func_sigs[f]]
    return f(*args)


def foo(data, func_list):
    var1, var2, var3 = init_variables(data)
    results = (len(func_list) + 1) * [0]
    for i in xrange(var1):
        for j, func in enumerate(func_list):
            results[j] += (call_func(func, data, var1, var2, var3))
        results[len(func_list)] += fixed_func()
    return results
```

The bigger question is why do you want to keep the signatures the way they are: are you keeping API compatibility or just don't want to refactor?

Comment: I am willing to refactor, I just haven't thought of a compelling solution to this. All the varying functions require the information from init_variables but return different values and don't need to be called at the same time.

(I'm working on a machine learning algorithm that optimizes subsets of parameters, the varying functions are actually functions that are used to calculate the gradients on those parameter subsets.)